# Unity: How to check if there is un-shown text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to check if there is un-shown text in the UI.
In other words, the width needed to show the entered text is larger than the width of gameobject that shows this text.

**Edit**:

The below answer is the solution for what I need, but I have another related question:
If there is an overflow how to know the last shown character or the first hidden character?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you tell us what hasn't worked?

Comment: I am thinking of making a duplicate of the game object and add contentsizefitter to the duplicated one. This will adjust the size of the duplicated one to fit all text. I can hide the duplicated one after comparing it's height with the height of the original one

Comment: There are many similar questions. Just type "unity detect text overflow" on Google...

Comment: @Hellium Thank you for your tip. I found and also I get a solution, but there is another question related to this question. Can you please read the edit and help me if you can?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below:

```
bool CheckTextWidth()
{
    float preferredWidth = LayoutUtility.GetPreferredWidth(text.rectTransform);
    float parentWidth = parentRect.rect.width;
    return (preferredWidth > (parentWidth-longestCharWidth));
}
```

Comment: parentRect?
Wherever you copied this from, you omitted some of it.